# What is the difference between "make modules" and "make modules_install"

Tags: linux, kernel, compile, kernel-module

I'm currently looking up compiling a custom kernel and I find various guides that first say `make modules` and then `make modules_install` in the step when you compile and install the modules while other just do `make modules_install`.

Could someone enlighten me and explain the difference (I would prefer them explained in newbie language: nothing too detailed, thanks).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `make modules` command will just compile the modules, leaving the compiled binaries in the build directory. `make modules_install` will make sure that there are compiled binaries (and compile the modules, if not) and install the binaries into your kernel's `modules` directory.

If you are sure that all modules compile without problems, you can use `make modules_install` directly.

Comment: `make modules_install` doesn't perform the compilation for me. Is this something which differs between systems?

Comment: `modules_install` does not include `modules`, i.e., nothing is built.

Answer (score 3):

prior to 2.6, you need `make modules`, while after 2.6, `make` will also do `make modules`